# final static array - untypical constant value

Tags: java

I have a bit untypical static constant value, which I wanted to declare in the following way:

```
protected static final int[][] a = new int [][] { {34,16}, {50,16}, {66,16}, {82,16}, {98,16}, {114,16}};
```

Unfortunately it's rejected.The field a cannot be declared static in non-static inner type unless initialized with a constant expression.

Just to be fully sure that we have the same overview of the situation, it's the field of the inner class.

I tried to declare it also as

```
protected static final int[][] a = { {34,16}, {50,16}, {66,16}, {82,16}, {98,16}, {114,16}};
```

It does work neither. :(

And even if I try to use static initializer, it's the same story:

```
protected static final int[][] a;
static { a = new int [][] { {34,16}, {50,16}, {66,16}, {82,16}, {98,16}, {114,16}}};
```

It's rejected, also when I remove new int[][].

Why it doesn't work? For sure I can skip static and tread it as non-static field, but if it's a constant value, why not to make it static?

Comment: Can we see the whole class? It sounds a lot like the problem isn't your declaration of `a`, but _where_ you're declaring `a`.

Comment: Where are you declaring it? It works fine if it is a global declaration.

Comment: @LouisWasserman He's told us it's being declared in an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed in accordance with [JLS §8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> **Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.**

The `int[][] a` you have declared is not a constant variable as it was not initialized with a constant expression (see [JLS §15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)). If `a` were a `String` or an `int`, for instance, and was initialized with a literal, it would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have something like:

```
class inner{
protected static final int[][] a = { {34,16}, {50,16}, {66,16}, {82,16}, {98,16}, {114,16}};
}
```

You can remove static and still access `a` directly.

```
class inner{
    protected final int[][] a = { {34,16}, {50,16}, {66,16}, {82,16}, {98,16}, {114,16}};
    }
```

inner classes can only have static constant fields.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the JLS, a constant expression is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value
>   of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is
>   composed using only the following:
>
> ...

what you have

```
new int [][] { {34,16}, {50,16}, {66,16}, {82,16}, {98,16}, {114,16}};
```

is not a constant expression.